# What line minimizes the area between the line and the parabola $x^2$ for $x \in (-1,1)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I want to minimize the area between a line and the parabola $x^2$ for $x$ between -1 and 1. More precisely, I want to minimize $\int_{-1}^{1}|x^2 - l(x)|$ where l(x) is a linear function. I tried some random examples and I found that the horizontal line $l(x) = \frac{1}{4}$ gives an area of $\frac{1}{2}$ which is the minimum of the examples I tried.

Comment: There is no absolute minimum.  For example, if you choose to take the line $y=\frac1n$, taking the line $y=\frac1{n+1}$ is guaranteed to reduce the area.

Comment: How do you define the area between the parabola and the line? Only the part fully enclosed, also the open parts? If $l$ is your line, do you want to minimize the integral of $l(x) - x^2$?

Comment: @Dirk They are talking about area, not integral. Inserting the example they found, it's pretty clear they likely mean they want to minimise the integral of $|l(x)-x^2|$.

Comment: @ Dirk.  Yes. I want to minimize the integral of $|l(x) - x^2|$

Comment: $y=0$ or any tangent line gives a zero integral

Comment: Are there any constraints to the problem? if any line works we can achieve any area we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to symmetry around $x=0$, the lines $l(x)=ax+b$ and $l(x)=(-a)x+b$ result in the same objective value. Since the objective function is convex in $(a,b)$, we conclude $a=0$.

So, all we need to find is $b$ such that $\int_0^1 |x^2-b| dx$ is minimized (due to symmetry we skip $x<0$). The optimal $b$ is clearly in $[0,1]$, so we can simplify the objective to:
$$\int_{0}^\sqrt{b} (b-x^2) dx+\int_\sqrt{b}^1 (x^2-b) dx = \left[ bx-\frac{1}{3}x^3 \right]_0^\sqrt{b}+\left[\frac{1}{3}x^3  - bx\right]_\sqrt{b}^1=\frac{4}{3}b\sqrt{b}-b+\frac{1}{3}.$$

Indeed the minimum occurs at $b=0.25$.